# Defining value traits for floating points

Tags: c++, template-specialization

while writing some code in c++, I want to express the notion that for a component of type X, its min value is `kMinValue` and its max value is `kMaxValue`. For this purpose, I did something like:

```
template <typename ComponentType>
struct CompTraits
{

};

template <>
struct CompTraits<unsigned char>
{
    typedef unsigned char ComponentType;
    enum{
        kMinValue = 0,
        kMaxValue = 255
    };              
};
```

And, I can refer `CompTraits<unsigned char>::kMinValue`. But, I am not able to understand the trick for floating data types. Could someone please help in defining the same thing for floats.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know about [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)? For example `std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::min()`.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't mean the float data type limits. I have my own component and it has its own limits, so when the component is of type float its limits are [0, 1.0], but when its unsigned char limits are [0, 255] and so on.

Comment: @Aarkan note that you can also specialize numeric_limits for your own data type, that would avoid the need to implement your `CompTraits` for all the already defined data types. See my answer's last edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `std::numeric_limits`, instead of your constants, but if you want only `kMinValue` and `kMaxValue` - you can use something like this

C++03

```
template<>
struct CompTraits<float>
{
   static const float kMinValue;
   static const float kMaxValue;
};

const float CompTraits<float>::kMinValue = std::numeric_limits<float>::min();
const float CompTraits<float>::kMaxValue = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
```

C++11

```
template<>
struct CompTraits<float>
{
   static constexpr float kMinValue = std::numeric_limits<float>::min();
   static constexpr float kMaxValue = std::numeric_limits<float>::max();
};
```

for your case you simply should use

```
template<>
struct CompTraits<float>
{
   static const float kMinValue = 0.0f;
   static const float kMaxValue = 1.0f;
};
```

Comment: I don't think it will compile (even in C++11). `min()` and `max()` are functions, so you have to use `constexpr` instead of `const`.

Comment: Note that the C++03 and C++11 versions are not equivalent.

Comment: You can also use the constants actually used by numeric_limits, such as FLT_MIN and FLT_MAX.

Comment: Thanks but I did not want data type limits, see my comment above.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you use `enum` for the constants. Enumeration constants can only be integers.

I suggest you use `static const` member variables instead (or `static constexpr` if you're using a C++11 compiler).

Answer (score 1):

**You can't used an `enum`** to define those values since an `enum` can only store integer values, you could use constants instead :

```
template <>
struct CompTraits<double>
{
    typedef double ComponentType;
    static const double kMinValue = 0.;
    static const double kMinValue = 1.;          
};
```

Also for standard numeric types you could take a look at the [std::numeric_limit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/) of the C++ STL.

**`numeric_limits<unsigned char>::min()`** will do the same thing as your `CompTraits<unsigned char>::kMinValue`, and it's implemented for every numeric types.

Also note that **you can specialize numeric_limit for your own data type** :

```
namespace std {
    template<>
    struct numeric_limits<YourType>
    {
        static const bool is_specialized = true;
        /* assuming YourType has a constructor from double */
        static const YourType min() throw() { return 0. };
        static const YourType max() throw() { return 1. };
    };
}
```

If you have doubt about the legitimacy of this approach, see :

> « A program may add template specializations
>   for any standard library template to namespace std. Such a
>   specialization (complete or partial) of a standard library template
>   results in undefined behavior unless the declaration depends on a
>   user-defined name of external linkage and unless the specialization
>   meets the standard library requirements for the original template.»
>   from [C++ 2003, §17.4.3.1/1](http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/spring13/CSCI-GA.2110-001/downloads/C++%20Standard%202003.pdf)